# C sharp Object Detection

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, accord.net

assume we have some aerial images (it is assumed that all of them are Perpendicular)
i want to detect Mountain, Road, Trees, River and Objects like this in images.

i have no experience with Image processing and machine learning yet. but i'm currently working on Accord.Net framework.

trough my researches i reached to this article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826377/Rapid-Object-Detection-in-Csharp#introduction

But it does't seem too work in my case.

whats the best way to do this?
is there any tutorial for C sharp implementation of this Purpose?

Comment: 1. stop asking for best things unless you specify what is good. 2. your post is too broad. what kind of answer do you expect here? given that you don't have any experience in both image processing and machine learning a complete answer to your question would require several books and years of mentorship. why don't you get experience with existing tutorials and resources first? detecting a mountain is totally different from detecting a road. how long would it take you to do your first brain surgery with no medical experience? start with the basics is the best advice I have to offer

Comment: @Piglet thanks piglet for your advice, I'm really sorry if my question seems too hard to answer. would you tell me where to start?

Comment: start with some fundamentals. doing everything you mentioned would most likely give some experienced researchers a hard time. at least if you want to do it well.